# heap priority pop multiple for performance

Tags: c++, boost, stl, priority-queue

I am using boost::heap::priority to reorder object according to timestamps.
It is for an ongoing process, there are always push and pop ( pop after object is 10ms in the heap)
I can see pop is taking cpu, I think if there was a way to remove multiple elements from heap and only after to rebuild the heap, performance would be better
Is there a way to do it with boost::heap::priority?
Is there a better structure to use?

I use c++ boost stl

Comment: Have you made a minimal benchmark? It depends on the data amount.

Comment: The heap data structure only knows which single element has the highest priority at any given time. It needs to do `O(log n)` work in `pop` operation to figure out the second highest (which becomes the first highest after `pop`, of course).  It can't give you more than one element at a time without this extra work.

Comment: Depending on your needs, perhaps you can re-structure things a bit, so (for example) you create a bucket of objects that fall within a 10 ms window, so it's trivial to remove all of them together? This would mean objects disappear at 10-20 ms instead of exactly at 10 ms though, so it isn't always suitable.

Comment: I'm with @JerryCoffin here.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I will look at your proposition, Thanks